# Changing person's profile picture in Picasa web?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

In Picasa it is possible to change a person's profile image when using "face-tagging".

I can not do the same or synchronize my settings to Picasa Web.

Any solutions?

For some reason, the Picasa web chose a picture of my son when he was 2 years old as the profile picture. (He is now 8).

Answer (score 1):

This used to be possible but doesn't seem possible anymore.

It used to be accessible this way:

1. In your Picasa Web, click the tab "People". You'll see a list of all people tagged as faces in your photos.
2. Hover the mouse over an entry to see editing options. There are several choices, but one that is now missing was called "pick thumbnail" or something like that. This is what you would use to specify which picture to use as that person's thumbnail.

I have no idea why this was removed.

Comment: I just installed the latest version of Picasa, and the option is there. It's called "Set as People Album Thumbnail".

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to the PEOPLE tab
2. Find the person whose thumbnail you want to change
3. Select a tagged photo of that person you want to use instead
4. Right click the thumbnai of that picture land select "Set as People Album Thumbnail"